# API для получения прошлой погоды

Tags: поиск-api, weather

Нужно получить температуру за каждый день 2015, но с сервисов которые предоставляют подобные данные - только  OpenWeatherMap, с ценой 900$

Есть ли более дешевые варианты ?

Comment: www.wunderground   com может этот подойдет